# Getting Permissions issue on sending the authenticated request to OAuth2.0 Django rest Framwork

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-oauth

I Have integrated the OAuth2.0 with django-rest-framework. When I send the authenticated request to my class based view I got this

```
{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

views.py

```
    from rest_framework import permissions
    from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import TokenHasReadWriteScope
    class LogoutView(APIView):
        """
            This will help in logout of user.
        """
        authentication_classes = ()
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope)

        def get(self, request):
            return Response({'s': 'd'})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from accounts.views import SignUpView, LoginView, LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view()),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view()),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view()),
]
```

And this is what my headers look like

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer 4A7qGgmHpbEWlJn5w4wCwxJ9jWfTZ5
```

This is the access token that I generated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have the following in your `settings.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
```

And:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 360000,
    'SCOPES': {'read': 'Read scope', 'write': 'Write scope', 'groups': 'Access to your groups'},
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 1800
}
```

For debugging purposes:

- Remove `authentication_classes = ()` from view.py
- Remove `TokenHasReadWriteScope` from view.py

If you want to make a logout endpoint, I would recommend using `oauth2_views` in your urls.py:

```
from oauth2_provider import views as oauth2_views
#.....

urlpatterns = [
    #....
    url(r'^logout/$', oauth2_views.RevokeTokenView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Still the same problem after removing TokenHasReadWriteScope

Comment: try and remove 'authentication_classes = ()' from your view

Comment: Glad I could help, and thanks for accepting the answer!
Look at my final edit, you should consider using 'oauth2_views'.

Comment: Okay!! Will surely look forward to it